# How can I package a python app using pytorch / transformers / Flask into a neat executable?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm using pytorch(+cuda), transformers, Flask and few other simpler dependencies in my python app under conda. The installation from my repo is quite straightforward for anyone experienced in this, but it still requires python and miniconda to be installed on the host. I've looked at pyinstaller and such as a way to package into a nice executable-plus-dependencies-directory type setup for easy distribution, but it seems the complexity of pytorch is too much of a challenge for pyinstaller and I get errors. By that point anyway, the dependency directory becomes massive and has what seems to me to be an overly complicated structure.

I'm definitely a noob at this, has anyone here done this specifically with pytorch / transformers?

I'm only interested in packaging for Windows 10 on x86_64 systems.

Cheers

Comment: The [Nuitka](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka) library is an excellent tool for this situation. Critics say it's unnecessarily slow, but that's because it does a lot of background optimizations on your code.